# Why OpenGL doesn't want compile my COMPUTE_SHADER?

Tags: c, opengl, compute-shader

I'm trying to compile simple compute shader in OpenGL but after many trial and error I finaly got error message from OpenGL from connected  `glDebugMessageCallback` and it outputs this message log from callback...

```
GL CALLBACK: ** GL ERROR ** type = 0x824c, severity = 0x9146, message = GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated. <program> has not been linked, or is not a program object.
GL CALLBACK: ** GL ERROR ** type = 0x824c, severity = 0x9146, message = GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated. <program> object is not successfully linked, or is not a program object.
```

Here is minimal reproducible code....

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>

GLFWwindow *window;
GLuint program;
GLuint compute_shader;

static const char *compute_shader_text =
"#version 430                                                        \n"
"                                                                    \n"
"layout (local_size_x = 8, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z=1) in;     \n"
"                                                                    \n"
"void main() {                                                       \n"
"}                                                                   \n";


void MessageCallback(GLenum source,GLenum type, GLuint id,GLenum severity, GLsizei length,const GLchar *message,const void *userParam) {
    fflush(stdout);
    fprintf(stderr, "GL CALLBACK: %s type = 0x%x, severity = 0x%x, message = %s\n",
            (type == GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR ? "** GL ERROR **" : ""),
            type, severity, message);
    fflush(stderr);
}

int main(void) {

    // Init glfw
    glfwInit();
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewInit();

    //Init logger
    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS);
    glDebugMessageCallback(MessageCallback, 0);

    // SHADER
    compute_shader = glCreateShader(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(compute_shader, 1, &compute_shader_text, NULL);
    glCompileShader(compute_shader);

    // PROGRAM
    program = glCreateProgram();
    printf("Compute program: %i\n", program);
    glAttachShader(program, compute_shader);
    glLinkProgram(program);

    glUseProgram(compute_shader);
}
```

Comment: Does this , `float buffer[SIZE] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}`, mean anything? You are pre setting your values to `0`.

Comment: @SnipingPoodle the line `glGetBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(buffer), buffer);` I try to retrive the buffer values, that line that you pointed out is joust fixing values to zeros since size is 8 I have puted in 8 zeros joust to be sure that the starting values are fixed on 0. Bug after glGetBufferSubData the values of buffer should be updated from compute shader :( but they are not :(

Comment: If you thought the line `glGetBufferSubData` is updating the buffers, it's not; it's actually just retrieving data from the shader.  I think it should be `glBufferSubData` instead to update the data.

Comment: You are lacking a `glMemoryBarrier`.

Comment: Hm @derhass it looks like that the problem is in `glUseProgram`, I have updated my question with new code and gl debug messages and it looks like something is wrong with shader program...

Comment: Well, `glUseProgram` requires a program object, not a shader object.

Comment: @dergass you saved my sanity, I swear that I would not figure this out.